# LPTHW Excercise 48 Help - Working with Tuples in Lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm currently going through LPTHW and I'm up to [excercise 48](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex48.html) and it's the first time I've hit a brick wall.

Here's the first part of the test case I've been given

```
from nose.tools import *
from ex48 import lexicon

def test_direction():
    assert_equal(lexicon.scan("north"), [('direction', 'north')])
    result = lexicon.scan("north south east")
    assert_equal(result, [('direction', 'north'),
                          ('direction', 'south'),
                          ('direction', 'east')])
```

[This question has been asked here before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881193/learn-python-the-hard-way-exercise-48-help), and I noticed my current solution so far is pretty identical to the [answer provided by robbyt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881193/learn-python-the-hard-way-exercise-48-help/7241227#7241227). Yet it still doesn't work.

```
def scan(thewords):

    directions = [('direction', 'north'), ('direction', 'south'), ('direction', 'east')]

    thewords = thewords.split()
    sentence = []

    for i in thewords:
        if i in directions:
            sentence.append(('direction', i))

        else:
            sentence.append(('error', i))


    return sentence
```

**So the question is: After taking the input (thewords), how do I search through the list of tuples correctly and then return the specific tuple it's a part of?**

Thanks in advance for any sort answers and advice, really stuck with this one.

Comment: Think about what you need `directions` to hold in your function. Does it need to hold the text `'direction'` three times?

Comment: Thanks, it looks as though I was simply over complicating things for myself. I simply changed it to a list containing only the second elements and got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So thanks to the hints from Thomas K & ed I managed to complete the exercise. Quite annoyed with myself now, it was all so straightforward now I look at it...

```
directions = ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west', 'down', 'up', 'down', 'right']
verbs = ['go', 'stop', 'kill', 'eat']
stops = ['the', 'in', 'at', 'of', 'from', 'at', 'it']
nouns = ['door', 'bear', 'princess', 'cabinet']


def scan(thewords):

    thewords = thewords.split()
    sentence = []

    for i in thewords:
        if i in directions:
            sentence.append(('direction', i))

        elif i in verbs:
            sentence.append(('verb', i))

        elif i in stops:
            sentence.append(('stop', i))

        elif i in nouns:
            sentence.append(('noun', i))

        elif i.isdigit():
            sentence.append(('number', convert_number(i)))

        else:            
            sentence.append(('error', i))

    return sentence

def convert_number(s):
    try:
        return int(s)

    except ValueError:
        return None
```

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by @Evee's first solution (thanks), here's my solution that passes all the tests. Perhaps it uses more code than the second solution, but it eliminates a loop outside of the only method defined.

```
class Lexicon(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mapping = {
              'direction':  ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west'],
              'verb':       ['go', 'kill', 'eat'],
              'stop':       ['the', 'in', 'of'],
              'noun':       ['door', 'bear', 'princess', 'cabinet']
              }
        self.mapping_categories = self.mapping.keys()

    def scan(self, input):
        self.result = []

        for word in input.split():
            try:
                self.result.append(('number', int(word)))
            except ValueError:
                for category, item in self.mapping.items():
                    if word.lower() in item:
                        found_category = category
                        break
                    else:
                        found_category = 'error'
                self.result.append((found_category, word))

        return self.result

lexicon = Lexicon()
```

Answer (score 2):

Using  a dictionary would make it much easier and faster.
Check out this code

```
directions = ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west', 'down', 'up', 'left', 'right', 'back']
verbs = ['go','stop','kill','eat']
stop_words = ['the', 'in', 'of', 'from', 'it']
nouns = ['door','bear','princess','cabinet']

lexicons = {}
for key in directions:
    lexicons[key] = 'direction'
for key in verbs:
    lexicons[key] = 'verb'
for key in stop_words:
    lexicons[key] = 'stop'
for key in nouns:
    lexicons[key] = 'noun'

def scan(sentence):
    tuples = []
    words = sentence.split()
    for word in words:
        try:
            tuples.append((lexicons[word],word))
        except KeyError:
            if word.isdigit():
                tuples.append(('number',int(word)))
            else:
                tuples.append(('error',word))
    return tuples
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much has been introduced by exercise 48, but I have a few comments on your solution above.

First, with a separate variable for each list of words, it's a bit difficult to maintain this code.  Second, `i` is generally only used as a variable when it's counting natural numbers from `0`.

Consider:

```
_LEXICON = dict(
    direction = ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west', 'down', 'up', 'down', 'right'],
    verb = ['go', 'stop', 'kill', 'eat'],
    stop = ['the', 'in', 'at', 'of', 'from', 'at', 'it'],
    noun = ['door', 'bear', 'princess', 'cabinet'],
    number = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'],
)

def scan(words):
    result = []

    for word in words.split():
        found_category = 'error'
        for category, category_lexicon in _LEXICON.items():
            if word in category_lexicon:
                found_category = category
                break

        result.append((found_category, word))

    return result
```

But we can do better; looking for items in a list is slow.  When you want to look something up, you want a dictionary:

```
_LEXICON = dict(...)
_LEXICON_INDEX = dict()
for category, words in _LEXICON:
    for word in words:
        _LEXICON_INDEX[word] = category

def scan(words):
    result = []

    for word in words.split():
        result.append((_LEXICON_INDEX.get(word, 'error'), word))

    return result
```

Of course, this doesn't actually pass all the tests in the exercise.  I'll leave it to you to fix my code.  ;)

Comment: Thanks for that, will have a play around with it tomorrow  to see if I can get it working using a dictionary instead.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your "directions" list will eventually contain tuples with something other than "direction" as the first entry (following on from @Thomas K's comment).

If you make a list of just the second elements of your tuples:

```
valid_words = [x[1] for x in directions]
```

Then modifying your code to do:

```
for i in thewords:
    if i in valid_words:
        sentence.append(directions[valid_words.index(i)])
```

will give you the relevant tuple.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but as it turns out I was simply overcomplicating things for myself. I appreciate your answer though and will keep it in mind if I find myself needing to do that in the future.

Also that's the first time I've seen a for loop written in the [] brackets like that, is that the same as writing...

`for x in directions`
`valid_words = [x[1]]`

?

Comment: It's a "list comprehension" (http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-list-comprehension). It's a quick way to process a sequence (list, tuple, string etc.) and output a list. The extra "if" argument is particularly useful, although I didn't use one in this example.