# Learn Python the Hard Way: Exercise 48 - AttributeError

Tags: python

I have been attempting to work my way through *Learn Python the Hard Way*, and on Exercise 48 I continue to get an error when I run `nosetests`. I am using code that other people have verified on the site to work, but no matter what I continue to get this error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: tests.ex48_tests.test_directions
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
        self.test(*self.arg)
    File "/Users/AlexanderMariona/Documents/Home/Programming/Python/Projects/Exercise 48/tests/ex48_tests.py", line 6, in test_directions
        assert_equal(lexicon.scan("north"), [('direction', 'north')])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'scan'
```

I get this error 6 times, one for each of my  test functions.

Here is what I'm using for my code:

lexicon.py:

```
class Lexicon(object):

    directions = ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west', 'down', 'up', 'down', 'right']
    verbs = ['go', 'stop', 'kill', 'eat']
    stops = ['the', 'in', 'at', 'of', 'from', 'at', 'it']
    nouns = ['door', 'bear', 'princess', 'cabinet']

    def scan(thewords):

        thewords = thewords.split()
        sentence = []

        for i in thewords:

            if i in directions:
                sentence.append(('direction', i))

            elif i in verbs:
                sentence.append(('verb', i))

            elif i in stops:
                sentence.append(('stop', i))

            elif i in nouns:
                sentence.append(('noun', i))

            elif i.isdigit():
                sentence.append(('number', convert_number(i)))

            else:            
                sentence.append(('error', i))

        return sentence

    def convert_number(s):
        try:
            return int(s)

        except ValueError:
            return None

lexicon = Lexicon()
```

(This was written by [Dairylee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7464350/2272087).)

ex48_tests.py:

```
from nose.tools import *
from ex48 import lexicon


def test_directions():
    assert_equal(lexicon.scan("north"), [('direction', 'north')])
    result = lexicon.scan("north south east")
    assert_equal(result, [('direction', 'north'),
                          ('direction', 'south'),
                          ('direction', 'east')])

def test_verbs():
    assert_equal(lexicon.scan("go"), [('verb', 'go')])
    result = lexicon.scan("go kill eat")
    assert_equal(result, [('verb', 'go'),
                          ('verb', 'kill'),
                          ('verb', 'eat')])


def test_stops():
    assert_equal(lexicon.scan("the"), [('stop', 'the')])
    result = lexicon.scan("the in of")
    assert_equal(result, [('stop', 'the'),
                          ('stop', 'in'),
                          ('stop', 'of')])


def test_nouns():
    assert_equal(lexicon.scan("bear"), [('noun', 'bear')])
    result = lexicon.scan("bear princess")
    assert_equal(result, [('noun', 'bear'),
                          ('noun', 'princess')])

def test_numbers():
    assert_equal(lexicon.scan("1234"), [('number', 1234)])
    result = lexicon.scan("3 91234")
    assert_equal(result, [('number', 3),
                          ('number', 91234)])


def test_errors():
    assert_equal(lexicon.scan("ASDFADFASDF"), [('error', 'ASDFADFASDF')])
    result = lexicon.scan("bear IAS princess")
    assert_equal(result, [('noun', 'bear'),
                          ('error', 'IAS'),
                          ('noun', 'princess')])
```

(This is copied verbatim from [LPTHW](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex48.html).)

setup.py:

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

config = {
    'name': 'Excercise 48',
    'description': 'LPTHW',
    'version': '0.1',
    'author': 'My Name',
    'author_email': 'My E-Mail',
    'url': 'None',
    'download_url': 'None',
    'packages': ['ex48'],
    'scripts': [],
    'install_requires': ['nose']
}

setup(**config)
```

And here is the directory of the package:

```
Exercise 48/
    bin/
    docs/
    ex48/
        __init__.py
        lexicon.py
    setup.py
    tests/
        __init__.py
        ex48_tests.py
```

What exactly is causing this error?

Comment: It happens because there's no function `scan` in the module `lexicon`. There's a method in the class `Lexicon`, but it will fail either because `self` is missing.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was hung up for some reason that there had to be a `Lexicon` class, but after removing that, it resolved the error. Thank you very much.

Comment: @bereal, you gave a good answer but in the Comments area. Why not use the Answers area?

Comment: @JimDeLaHunt good point, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error happens because there's no function `scan` in the module `lexicon`. There's a method in the class `Lexicon`, then it should be called like a method (note that `self` argument is missing).

On the other hand, `Lexicon` does not have to exist as a class at all, `scan` can be a module-level function.